# How to properly override console.warn in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am overriding `console.warn` to capture the warnings that are printed into the console of the web browser like this and the file in which I am doing this is `track.js` shown below. The code works absolutely fine.

File 1

```
// Filename - track.js

function getWarnStatements() {
  window.warnStatements = [];
  var oldWarn = console.warn;
  console.warn = function (message) {
  oldWarn.apply(console, arguments);
   window.warnStatements.push({
    type: 'console.warn',
    data: message,
   });  
 };
}
```

File 2

```
// Filename - xyz.js

console.warn('Hello World');
```

Let's say I have used `console.warn()` in some other file which is `xyz.js` and both `track.js` and `xyz.js` runs at the same time. When we normally check the browser console for the warning we will see the file name on the right side of the warning in the console and when we click on the filename it will take us to the javascript file in which the `console.warn` was written.

**ISSUE**

Check the image below. Instead of showing `xyz.js` it is showing `track.js`. How can i prevent this behavior. I want it to take the user to the correct file where `console.warn` was used instead of the file where I am over riding it because it will result in misleading the other developers to the wrong file.

[image]

Comment: Inside the file `xyz.js`, try to define `var $warn = console.warn;`, then throwing a warning: `$warn('test');`. How is the result?

Comment: @Tân Tried it .. Still the same. The thing is that the `track.js` is the first file that runs and all the other files that have `console.warns` run after it. Is there any other way by which we can achieve the same, i mean capturing `console.warn` messages ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking a general view the problem is to intercept and capture arguments supplied in calls to `console.warn` and complete the intention of showing warnings on the console with an indication of where the warning arose in code.

First up you can't hide from a real `console.warn` call where the call was made from, so simplify matters by dropping all subterfuge. The two options that remain are to produce a full or partial trace of where calls to the substituted `warn` function are made from.

1. Full trace.

   In the intercepted warn function make a `console.trace` call.
2. Partial trace.

   In the intercepted warn function create a new Error object, slice one or more lines from the object's [`stack` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error/stack) and log them  to the console without using `console.warn`.

The biggest problem with the second option is that `errorObject.stack` is not standardized in web standards - while you may test it and achieve outstanding results (with minor differences) in browsers tried, there is no guarantee that it will work in all browsers.

In conclusion solutions that you implement depend on the use case - is it for in-house testing, or if on the web do you need to sniff the presence of Error Object `stack` properties before using them.

As a side note, console.xxx functions accept multiple parameters which the posted substitute does not record.

---

Here's a quick example showing the `console.warn` intermediate function (anonymous in the post) being called directly. Which lines to slice may need fine tuning, and if emoji are not acceptable then substitute as needed:

```js
function interWarn() {
    let args = arguments;
    // save arguments;
    let err = new Error( "trace");
    var stack = err.stack;
    if( !stack) try {
        throw err;
    }
    catch( err) {
        stack = err.stack;
    }
    if( stack) {
        stack = stack.split('\n').slice(1,3).join('\n');
        console.info('⚠️ Warning from\n%s\n%s', stack, '');
    }
    else console.trace();
    console.log.apply(console, args);
}
function foo() {
   interWarn("foo warning, %s", "okay?");
}
foo();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for investing your time to answer. Could you please edit your answer and put in a really short example for the `console.trace` and  partial trace. because full trace will be too big in the console to read for some people :)

Comment: @MohammadBasit done. The example should fall back to `console.trace` if nothing else works.  Apparently some browsers only add (or added) the `stack` property to an Error object after it has been thrown.

Comment: A downside to this approach is that filtering in Dev Tools to show only warnings or errors won't show these messages, since they didn't actually invoke `console.warn()` or `console.error()`